# Odd or even in r

Tags: r

```
    persnr     date   
411223-6213 2011-01-19 
420211-6911 2012-01-19 
420604-7716 2007-09-01 
430404-8558 2011-09-01 
431030-7030 2011-09-01
440127-0055 2012-09-01
```

I want to create a new column for `persnr` if the 10th digit is odd or even.
The new column will they be true or false depending on whether the 10th digit of `persnr` is odd or even. odd=true, even=false

I also would like to create another column för 'date' so for example 2011-09-01 is fall and in the new column fall=true 
2012-01-19 is spring and in the new column spring=false.

This is certainly basic but I am a new user in the R and may not be right on it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output ?

Comment: Which months are fall and spring for you? I know it depends on your hemisphere but I don't know anywhere that thinks January is spring.

Comment: Note to everyone using `substr`: The `stringr` package has a `str_sub` function that lets you use negative numbers to index from the end of a string. So `str_sub(my.data$persnr,-1,-1)` gets you the last character.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `substr`.  Not sure if you count the `-` character also.  In that case,

```
 v1 <- as.numeric(substr(df1$persnr,10,10))
```

Or else replace `10` by `11` as in @nico's post

```
 df1$newCol <- as.logical(v1%%2)
```

I would prefer to have it as a logical column, but if you need to change it to 'odd', 'even'

```
df1$newCol <- c('even', 'odd')[df1$newCol+1L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Generate the data
my.data <- data.frame(
  persnr=c("411223-6213", "420211-6911",
           "420604-7716", "430404-8558",
           "431030-7030", "440127-0055"),
  date = c("2011-01-19", "2012-01-19",
           "2007-09-01", "2011-09-01",
           "2011-09-01", "2012-09-01"))

# Get the 10th digit of persnr using substring, then check the reminder
# of its division by 2 to determine if it is odd or even
# Note that I get the 11th char as there is a - in the middle of the number
digit.10 <- substr(my.data$persnr, 11, 11)
my.data$evenOdd <- ifelse(as.integer(digit.10)%%2, "odd", "even")
my.data$evenOdd <- factor(my.data$evenOdd, levels=c("odd", "even"))
```

To find the season of each date:

```
# Get month and day, ignore year
month.day <- strftime(my.data$date, format="%m-%d")
# Now check which season we're in -- ASSUMING NORTHERN HEMISPHERE, change if needed
# Also note that the dates of solstices and equinoxes are variable so
# this is approximative...

# Set everyone to winter
my.data$season <- "Winter"

# Find indices for the other seasons
spring <- which(month.day >= "03-21" & month.day < "06-21")
summer <- which(month.day >= "06-21" & month.day < "09-21")
fall <- which(month.day >= "09-21" & month.day < "12-21")

my.data$season[spring] <- "Spring"
my.data$season[summer] <- "Summer"
my.data$season[fall] <- "Fall"

my.data$season <- factor(my.data$season, levels = 
                  c("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"))
```